# Where should I put external web service processing logic in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails application I use some external web services: twitter, google picasa, flickr etc.

Where should I put code related to processing responses of these services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create abstract models (non-persistent) for each of these so each abstract model can be responsible for processing requests and so forth.

Data structure could look like this:

```
app/models/web_services/
  google.rb
  twitter.rb
```